If a (commutative) ring (with unity) has a unique minimal prime ideal, is the nilradical necessarily prime?
The question is

If a (commutative) ring (with unity) has a unique minimal prime ideal, is the nilradical prime?

I just thought of this as the converse is true (and it follows immediately from the fact that the nilradical is the intersection of all prime ideals).
My attempt: Let $\mathfrak p$ be the unique minimal prime ideal of $A$, then $\DeclareMathOperator{\Nil}{Nil}\Nil(A)\subseteq\mathfrak p$. I don't see any obvious way to prove the reverse inclusion.

I would like to mention a couple of aspects: 1) the notion of primality can be defined for general bilateral (or two-sided, as English calls them) ideals of a not necessarily commutative ring. In this setting, any nondegenerate ring (with unity) has the property that its set of prime ideals is inductive when ordered by the dual (reverse) of inclusion; 2) as an immediate consequence of 1), the radical of any ideal $I$ can be expressed as the intersection of all prime ideals containing $I$ and minimal with this property; (to be cont.)

(cont.) 3) in particular, the nilradical of any ring is expressed as the intersection of all the minimal prime ideals.
Hence, the hypothesis that a given ring has a unique minimal prime ideal leads to the immediate conclusion that the nilradical is equal to that unique ideal and therefore itself prime. As in general an inductive set with a unique maximal element has a maximum (the unique maximal), it also turns out that under such a particular assumption the unique minimal prime is actually the minimum prime.

It is enough to show that the minimal prime $\newcommand{\frp}{\mathfrak p}\frp_0$ is contained in all the primes. Let $\frp$ be a prime ideal of a ring $A$. Consider the localisation $A_{\frp}$. Primes in $A_{\frp}$ correspond to primes in $A$ contained in $\frp$. This localisation has some minimal prime ideal $\frp_1$ (Zorn's lemma). Lift it to a prime ideal $\frp_1$ (abuse of notation) of $A$ contained in $\frp$. Then, $\frp_1\supseteq\frp_0$. Going back to $A_\frp$, we get that $\frp_1=\frp_0$. Hence, $\frp_0\subseteq\frp$. Since $\frp$ was arbitrary, we get that $\frp_0\subseteq\operatorname{Nil}(A)$. This completes the proof.

What's the purpose of this question if you already know the answer?

@Mark: I thought it was encouraged. I was initially going to post this as a question, but in the process of typing, I figured out an answer. (Though I have to wait 48 hours before accepting it.)

By the way, note that you don't really have to use localization here. Just every prime ideal of $A$ contains some minimal prime ideal (it is exactly the same argument using Zorn's lemma), and so in this case must contain the unique minimal prime.

@Mark: that's right too. I should have seen that, thanks.
